# Using Python, Divide a String into Two halves if specific characters are in center of String

Tags: python, string

A 101-String is a String that contains 1s and 0s where the substring `'101'` is located in the center of string. A 101 string has at least 3 characters i-e the shortest 101-string is `'101'`

For example the String `'110101001'` is a 101-String because the substring 101 divides the original string in two equal halves. In other words, if we take the substring **101** out from the original string, we have two strings **110** and **001** of equal length.

Write a program, that asks user to enter a string and print `True` if the string is 101-string and `False` if it's not.  if the string contains any characters other than 1s and 0s, program should print `False`. if the String's length is less than 3 characters, the program should print `False` as well.

Comment: What have you tried and what specific problem you were not able to solve?

Comment: I have solved it using sets. But i am curious if there is another way we can do this without using sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can check if it's a 101 String using sets. We can check if the string contains 101 using `.find()` function. Finally, we will split the string using String slicing.

```
def check(string) :


    p = set(string)

    # declare set of '0', '1' .
    s = {'0', '1'}

    if s == p or p == {'0'} or p == {'1'}:
        print("True")
    else :
        print("False")


if __name__ == "__main__" :

    string = input("Enter 101-string")
    # function calling
    check(string)
    substring = "101"
    if len(string)<2:
        print("False")
    if substring in string:
            print("101 String found")
    print("length of String is: ",len(string))
    find_101 = string.find('101')
    print("Location of 101 is", find_101)
    end_101 = find_101+2;
    print("String 101 ends at index:",end_101)
    s1 = string[:find_101]
    second_part = end_101+1; 
    s2 = string[second_part:]
    print(s1,s2)
    if len(s1) == len(s2):
        print("True")
    else:
        print("Not a 101 String")
        print("False")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need only 3 conditions for a valid 101 string:

1. The string length is odd (checked using modulo)
2. It is composed of `'0'`/`'1'` only (checked using `set.issubset`)
3. There is `'101'` in the middle (checked using slicing):

```
def is101(s):
    x = (len(s)-2)//2
    return bool(len(s)%2) & set(s).issubset('01') &  (s[x:x+3] == '101')
```

Example:

```
>>> is101('110101001')
True

>>> is101('')
False

>>> is101('11010100')
False

>>> is101('xxx101xxx')
False
```